# How to change sender mobile number in Android SMS service

Tags: android, sms

I'm sending SMS in my Android App,

```
 SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String number = "1234567890";
    sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, "Test SMS Message--Successful", null, null);
```

It is working fine. My Question is, Is it possible to add string/text instead of Sender Mobile Number? so that in the recipient mobile, the sender's mobile  number will be appeared as that string/text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Here are multiple reasons why:

- When you send an sms, using `SmsManager` you encode it with the content - the actual text message itself. You also encode it with the phone number you are sending it to. And you encode the message center number to the message. That is all you get to encode. Then Android/hardware handles sending it over to the cell phone tower where it is then out of your hands.
- If you somehow tried to encode the recipient phone number as text, then the carrier would have no idea how to handle the message. It wouldn't have anywhere to send it too.
- Cell phones do not have inbound Caller (or sms) ID - unless the number is already programmed, of course.
- When the carrier network is sending an sms, it goes through a message center. The message center determines what data is forwarded to the recipient phone. The message centers currently available just do not support what you're wanting - at least not to the consumer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Cell phones do not have inbound Caller (or sms) ID", surely you always see the number of the phone calling (or texting) you, without having to do any "programming" on the phone?

Comment: I guess I should say that the do not have inbound Caller Name ID. By that I mean that they cannot get caller name from the network. That is why unknown numbers always appear as just that - numbers. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to change the sender phone number, but you need to use a third party SMS Gateway. You can reroute the SMS to come from a phone number that you register for your app.

Twilio - http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app

TextMagic - http://www.textmagic.com/app/pages/en/products/bulk-sms-gateway-api

Comment: If they can do it, we can do it somehow, too.