# Android Send SMS with App name

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I wish to send SMS message with the App name as the source address.
Meaning I will see the App name as the sender instead of my own number.
This is my code:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, "App name", "Message", null, null);
```

I get the message, but the sender is my own number.
How can I change the sender to be the App name?

Comment: I think you need a gateway to mask the id of the sender....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hiding the sender native android is not possible, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590131/982161)

BUT.....

Using a 3rd [party service gateway](https://www.twilio.com/console/dev-tools/api-explorer/sms/sms-mms-create) (where price can apply)

```
public class TwilioTest { 
 // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account 
 public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC......."; 
 public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "98......."; 

 public static void main(String[]args) throws TwilioRestException { 
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 

     // Build the parameters 
     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+0189899768798")); 
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "SupeUSer GmbH")); 
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "this is the body")); 
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MediaUrl", "ccccurlcccc"));  

     MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory(); 
     Message message = messageFactory.create(params); 
     System.out.println(message.getSid()); 
 } 
}
```